# How to decrypt 256-bit AES key with initialization vector and decryption key when the key is 21-22 characters?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am quite new to the field of encryption.

I have an encrypted string that I receive from a website which is AES 256 encrypted. In their return parameters, I am given a dictionary containing the following key-value pairs in a JSON table (pseudo-code):

```
{
    ct: ciphertext-key (i assume)
    iv: initialization vector
    s: salt
}
```

All three are strings and the decryption key I receive from another endpoint varies from 21-22 characters in length. I know that AES 256 is usually 16 bits for a decryption key, so this is unusual to me.

So, how do I decrypt the encrypted message given the iv, ct, salt and encryption key (which i assume is the wrong length..?)

Am I doing something wrong? If anybody can help me, I would greatly appreciate your insight into this enquiry.

Comment: You confuse bits and bytes. AES-256 uses a 256 bits / 32 bytes key (a 16-byte key is applied by AES-128). The salt rather indicates that the key could be derived in combination with a passphrase (of arbitrary length) and a key derivation function (KDF). However, you will have to ask the encrypting side for the details (especially which KDF (e.g. PBKDF2) and which KDF parameters (e.g. iteration count, digest etc.) are used).

Comment: Beyond Topaco's notes, since you haven't given actual examples, the encoding could be just about anything, so you'll need to know the encoding of the values you have (ASCII, hex, Base64, b64u would all be reasonable options, but there are more), and you'll need to know the block cipher mode (CBC, CTR, EBC, GCM, etc). If you're trying to learn reverse-engineering, Stack Overflow likely isn't much help (you may want to start reading similar questions at https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com). Otherwise, you need to look at the encrypting code or spec. There is no single standard here.